# Visual Studio 2012 Add New Class Missing Template

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've just installed VS2012 Ultimate side by side with VS2010 and it seems the standard templates are broken. I cannot add a class nor a console application.

File > New > File dialog contains the "Visual C# Class" template

but Right Click Project > Add > Class dialog does not contain the "Visual C# Class" template

Also File > New Project only contains MVC4 and not things like Console Application even if I change framework version and left filter.

EDIT: This only occurs after installing update 1. We have tried reinstalling, repairing, deleting the templates cache and reinstalling templates. We're considering working without update 1 at the moment, but there doesn't seem to be a way to uninstall just the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrupted ISO supplied, tried another from msdn and all fine now.